# How to replicate this Python code in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop

This is a silly game written in Python, I was wondering how to reproduce it in Java:

```
name = ''

while name != 'your name': 
   print('Please type your name.')
   name = input()

print('Thank you!')
```

Basically, it requests to write the string "your name" to break the while loop, now, I've tried this code in Java but it throws an error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sillyGame {

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    String name = "";

    while (name != "your name"){
      System.out.println("Please type your name");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      name = input.next();
      input.close();
    }

    System.out.println("thank you");
  }
}
```

The error is: "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException"

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `!name.equals("your name")` **and** remove `input.close()`.

Comment: To get rid of the `Exception`, you can move the `Scanner` declaration to the top of the `main` method and remove `input.close();` line.

use `name = input.nextLine()` insted of `name = input.next()`  because `next()` method will only consider the input till a space, `nextLine()` method will consider the input till `\n`.

put this condition in while loop `!name.equals("your name")` since `name != "your name"` compares the address not the values in java.

Comment: @Mahesh and Elliot, Thanks a lot for your insight, now the code runs great and I've learned important points in the process